# Calling storedprocedure with in a mysql function

Tags: mysql

Can i call a stored procedure inside a mysql function. I tried but it throws syntax error. Is it possible?

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `fn_abcd`$$

CREATE FUNCTION `fn_abcd`(orderItem BIGINT(45),quantity INT) RETURNS double
BEGIN

    DECLARE TotalNetValue DOUBLE;
   set TotalNetValue = call sp_abcd(orderItem,quantity);
    RETURN TotalNetValue;
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I think you need to use INOUT parameters to get your output. Can you check the documentation ?

Answer (score 0):

A stored procedure has no return value. You simply cannot do this:

SET someVar = CALL someProcedure();

If you need to retreive some value computed in the procedure, you need to either:

- have your stored procedure write the data in a session variable (`SELECT something INTO @var`) (this is ugly, but it works)
- use an [`INOUT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-procedure.html) parameter
- rewrite the procedure as a function

It is understood that most drivers (JDBC, PDO) will treat the result of the last `SELECT` statement executed in a stored procedure, as the result of a query like `CALL some_procedure()`. This feature is [specific to the MySQL client/server protocol](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/faqs-stored-procs.html#qandaitem-B-4-1-14), the MySQL SQL syntax has no equivalent.